# Bootstrap img-rounded with .col class not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap framework page, which having two images.

**1st image :** This image has two classes : col-sm-12 and img-rounded .

**2nd image :** This image has only one class : img-rounded.

The problem is , for the first image, the image having no border radius. But if I remove col-sm-12 from the tag , then this border-radius is clearly visible. What is wrong in these two case ?

Why for 1st case, border-radius not showing ?

**[Fiddle here](https://plnkr.co/edit/re581rwI3VKBl7LG57nD?p=preview)**

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:red;">
  <img class="col-sm-4 img-rounded" 
  src="http://images.indianexpress.com/2014/11/doordarshan422.jpg" >
</div>
<br>
<div class="row" style="background-color:red;">
  <img class="img-rounded" 
  src="http://images.indianexpress.com/2014/11/doordarshan422.jpg" >
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have now clear your issue?

Comment: understand my point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply the `img-rounded` class with the `col-sm-4` then the img tag occupies the padding right and left of `15px` of the class col-sm-4 and img-rounded class has `border-radius` `6px` only, So its not apply in your first case.

If you want to apply in first case then increase the `border-radius` and set it to `greater then 15px`.

may be you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply your `col-sm-4` class to the `div` containing the image, not the image itself:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background-color:red;">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img class="img-rounded" 
           src="http://images.indianexpress.com/2014/11/doordarshan422.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know , but my question is why I img-rounded not working with col-sm-4 class along-with ?